# Java - User String Input Convert to 2D Array of 6x6

Tags: java, arrays

I have a question regarding Java code implementation for the following scenario,

1. Get User Input [String from Scanner]
2. Convert the String input to 1D Array
3. From the 1D char array, populate it accordingly to 2D char array based on positions,
   [0][0], [0][1] etc

What I have done is as follows,

charArray has been created as a 6 by 6 array.`char[][] charArray = new char[6][6];`

```
Scanner scn = new Scanner (System.in);
System.out.print("String text: "); //Text from user
String str= scn.nextLine();
str = str.replaceAll("\\s+","");
char[] cArray = text.toCharArray(); //Convert String to char array

for (int i = 0; i < cArray.length; i++)
{
        for (int row = 0; row < charArray.length; row++)
        {

            for (int col = 0; col < charArray[row].length; col++)
             {

                 System.out.println("i = " + i);
                 //charArray[row][col] = letters[i]; //I'm supposed to put in the converted String to char and put into the 2D Array of 6 by 6. When I executed the script, there is an array out of bound exception 
                 System.out.println("charArray[" + row + "]" + "[" + col + "]" + "cArray[" + i + "]");
                 ++i;
                 System.out.println("End of col for loop");
              }
                   System.out.println("End of row for loop");

         }           
              i = i;

    }    
    System.out.println("End of i for loop");
```

It seems from the printing of messages, I could get the text's i position and to it's corresponding 2D array positions. But I could not populate the values by assigning.

I appreciate any tips and guidance for the above case.

Thank you very much.

Comment: On which array is the exception? `cArray`, `charArray` or `charArray[row]`?

Comment: Sorry, I have re-edited the codes.
This the code which has the exception, charArray[row][col] = letters[i];

Comment: how did you define `letters`?

Comment: Split your `charArray[row][col] = letters[i]` to several array-access. So you get the concrete array with the exception. `char c = letters[i]; char[] tmp = charArray[row]; tmp[col] = c;`

Comment: It has been replaced by cArray.

Comment: the exception will be thrown if user input length < 36 (6x6) so the 2 inner loops will loop (total 36) but `cArray` length is smaller, so cArray[i] will throw exception when `i>cArray.length`, i am looking into your sol if i can find a better way to do the task

Answer (score 0):

I didn't get your question.
But if you want to store in 6*6 character array without getting exception.
Here is the code how to do it

```
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    String s = sc.nextLine();
    sc.close();
    s=s.replaceAll("\\s+", "");
    char []ch = s.toCharArray();
    char [][]charArray = new char[6][6];
    int i=0, j=0;

    for(int k=0;k<ch.length;k++)
    {


        if(i<=5 && j<=5)charArray[i][j] = ch[k];
        j++;
        if(j>5) {
            j=0;
            i++;
        }
        if(i>5 && j>5) break;

    }
```

Comment: yes, this sol works, though you are missing a + `"\\s+"` and `sc.close();`

Comment: Thanks Kangkan! This works. I'm going to digest this logic.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to make sure the user has entered 36 characters exactly, then you can just copy the char array.

[**Live Demo**](http://ideone.com/QI0WnF)

```
Scanner scn = new Scanner (System.in);
System.out.print("String text: ");
String str = "";

// Read 6x6 characters
while (str.toCharArray().length != 36)
{
        System.out.print("Enter 36 characters: ");
        str = scn.nextLine().replaceAll("\\s+","");
}

char[] cArr = str.toCharArray();

// Print in 6x6 grid
for(int i=0; i<36; i++)
{
    System.out.print((i%6==0?"\n ":" ")+cArr[i]);
}
System.out.println();
```

And you could use that 1D array as a flat 2D array, or parse them into a 2D array in this way.

```
System.out.println("-------------------");

char[][] cMat = new char[6][6];

// Parse it into 6x6 matrix
for(int i=0; i<36; i++)
{
    cMat[i/6][i%6] = cArr[i];
}

// Print 6x6 matrix
for(int i=0; i<6; i++)
{
    for(int j=0; j<6; j++)
    {
        System.out.print(" "+cMat[i][j]);
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```